# Progress Bar Dinamico Bootstrap MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, bootstrap

Buen día foro, una ayuda para poder generar un `ProgressBar Dinámico` con datos extraído de una consulta `mysql`.

**Progress Bar**

```
    <?php 
            foreach($clientes as $cliente):
            $id = $cliente->identificador;

            $q = (SolicitudData::getGrafics($id));
                foreach($q as $p):
    ?>


    <div class="progress-group">
        <span class="progress-text"> &nbsp;</span>
        <span class="progress-number"><?php echo "<b>".$id."</b>"; ?> <b>|</b> <?php if($p->cliente_id != null){echo $p->getIdentificador()->razon;} ?></span>
            <div class="progress">
               <div id="progress-ser" class="progress-bar progress-bar-nuby progress-bar-striped active" style="width:0%"><?php echo $p->svr; ?></div>
           </div>
    </div>


    <?php 
        endforeach;
    endforeach;

?>
```

**Hasta aquí tengo el siguiente resultado.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora solo requiero que mi `progress bar` sea dinámico de acuerdo a los datos de obtenidos desde mi base de datos en porcentaje, he estado verificando al parecer se debe de utilizar `js` para que sea dinámico, alguien me puede dar una idea. Saludos

Comment: cuanto es el valor maximo? o el 100% a cuanto equivale ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="progress">
    <?php 
    $valorMin = 0;
    $valorMax = 250;
    $valorObtenido = 88;
    ?>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-nuby progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<?php echo $valorObtenido; ?>" aria-valuemin="<?php echo $valorMin; ?>" aria-valuemax="<?php echo $valorMax; ?>" style="width: <?php echo ($valorObtenido*100)/$valorMax; ?>%">
        <span class="sr-only"><?php echo $valorObtenido; ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```